# How to resolve the error 134 while running the command npm run build in the react app?

Tags: reactjs, production, dev-to-production, npm-run, npm-build

I am running the "npm run build" command in the frontend folder and it is showing error 134. Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.37",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.2.3",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.7.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.22.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.0",
    "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
    "country-state-city": "^3.0.1",
    "overlay-navbar": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-alert": "^7.0.3",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^3.1.1",
    "react-rating-stars-component": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "typewriter-effect": "^2.18.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000/"
}
```

I have deleted the package-lock.json file and node_modules folder and runned the command npm install but the issue isn't solved and it is showing the error again.

---

---

---

Comment: share the error message in your question

Comment: Well, it was resolved after I have updated my node version. Thanks for your response.